# How can iterate over JSON object and print its properties and their values?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to navigate each property in the JSON below in JavaScript. The below JSON contains two records for reference but in real time will have numerous such records.

{"Record_0":[{"Status":"CREATED","CreatorLoginId":"sandhya","Name":"G1"}],"Record_1":[{"Status":"CREATED","CreatorLoginId":"San","Name":"G2"}]}

I want to get the values of the fields "Status", "CreatorLoginId" and "Name" to assign them to something else.

How should I do it?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to get the values of the fields "Status", "CreatorLoginId" and "Name".

Comment: Can you post other records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var myJSON = JSON.parse('{"Record_0":[{"Status":"CREATED","CreatorLoginId":"sandhya","Name":"G1"}],"Record_1":[{"Status":"CREATED","CreatorLoginId":"San","Name":"G2"}]}');
            for(var pr in myJSON)
            {
                console.log(myJSON[pr][0].Status);
                console.log(myJSON[pr][0].CreatorLoginId);
                console.log(myJSON[pr][0].Name);
            }
```

Comment: This can be the solution if I know the field names beforehand. I do not know them in this case.

Comment: Rewrite the question because you write: _I want to navigate each property in the JSON below_

Comment: @PankajDwivedi I have rewritten the code to satisfy new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Print how? If you mean output to the js console it would be

```
for (index in object) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + object[index]);
}
```

If you mean add it to a web page, just replace console.log with a little markup:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parentID');
for (index in object) {
    parent.innerHTML += index + ': ' + object[index] + '<br>';
}
```

For nested objects (including arrays)

```
function print(object, parent) {
    for (index in object) {
        if (typeof object[index] == 'object') {
            print(object[index});
        }
        parent.innerHTML += index + ': ' + object[index] + '<br>';
    }
}
```

EDIT: don't forget to `JSON.parse():` the string first before iterating

Answer (score 0):

//Iterating through the groups

for (var   currentRecord   in   groupInformation)

{

```
store.data.items.push({serial: {}, groupName: {}, createdBy: {}, status: {} });
store.data.items[iNoOfGroups].serial = iNoOfGroups + 1;
store.data.items[iNoOfGroups].groupName = groupInformation[currentRecord][0].Name;
store.data.items[iNoOfGroups].createdBy = groupInformation[currentRecord][0].CreatorLoginId;
store.data.items[iNoOfGroups].status = groupInformation[currentRecord][0].Status;
iNoOfGroups++;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`var myJSON = JSON.parse('{"Record_0":[{"Status":"CREATED","CreatorLoginId":"sandhya","Name":"G1"}],"Record_1":[{"Status":"CREATED","CreatorLoginId":"San","Name":"G2"}]}');`

```
for(var key in myJSON){
   console.log(myJSON[key][0].Status);
   console.log(myJSON[key][0].CreatorLoginId);
   console.log(myJSON[key][0].Name);
}`
```